# Is (x|y|...)∈set the same as x∈set&&y∈set&&...?

Tags: pattern-matching, syntax, core-language, assumptions

I've sometimes seen that this operator is used to specify that *each of given variables* is in some set, e.g. `Reals`. Like `(x|y|z) ∈ Reals` as a shorthand for `x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals && z ∈ Reals`. This was in the context of specifying `Assumptions` to functions like `Simplify` or `Integrate`.

But I remember that when I tried something like this (don't remember exactly what), for some reason it gave me unexpected results, so I've been staying clear of this syntax for a while.

I've read the [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) on the `Alternatives` operator,

> $p_1|p_2|\ldots$
>
> is a pattern object that represents any of the patterns $p_i$.
>
> If a named pattern such as `x_` appears in $p_i$ that are not used in a particular match, then the named pattern is taken to have a value that is a zero-length sequence `Sequence[]`.

But that didn't make it clear what the "any" means.

Now I'm wondering: what is the difference between the two variants? `FullSimplify` for equality doesn't appear to say `True`, so I assume they are different. What are the conditions for `(x|y|z)∈Reals` to mean exactly that each of $x$, $y$ and $z$ is in $\mathbb R$, as does the `&&`-chained version?

Comment: Note that (5 | 4) \[Element] Integers is True while (5 | 4.2) \[Element] Integers is False. So the pattern using | requires that both be True, hence is effectively an AND operation.

Comment: Not sure off-hand what the behavior of `Element[a|b, set]`, but you can use `Element[{a,b}, set]` to get the behavior equivalent to `Element[a,set] && Element[b,set]`.

Comment: To give another example of what @bills wrote, `LogicalExpand[! LogicalExpand[! exp1]]` will expand exactly to `exp2` (see [Element](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html), under Properties&Relations). The `Element` documentation also states that all elements need to be part of the domain for the `(x|y|z)∈Reals` syntax, answering your original question directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
exp1 = (x | y | z) ∈ Reals;
exp2 = x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals && z ∈ Reals;
exp3 = {x, y, z} ∈ Reals
```

As stated in [Element >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Element.html) that (1) `exp1` is equivalent to `exp3`, and (2) `exp3` evaluates to `exp1` *"if its truth or falsity cannot immediately be determined."*

For `exp1` and `exp2`, as observed by bill s and Thies Heidecke in comments, we can show that  `!exp1` is equal to  `! exp2`:

```
LogicalExpand[! exp1] == LogicalExpand[! exp2]
```

> True

An alternative way is to `Simplify` `exp1` assuming `exp2`, and vice versa.

```
Assuming[exp1,  Simplify[exp2]]
```

> True

```
Assuming[exp2, Simplify[exp1]]
```

> True

Comment: Just a reminder. I'm not exactly sure but I believe since your answer consists only of code, the post popped up in the "Low-quality queue".

Comment: thank you @halirutan. I will add a few words.

Comment: Did you mean that `exp1` is equivalent to `exp3`, not `exp2` in the (1), and that `exp3` evaluates to `exp1`, not `exp2` does in (2)?

Comment: @Ruslan, right. I will edit in  a moment.

Comment: To future readers: don't fall into the trap of thinking that this extends to other operators: e.g. `(x|y)>0` is not_equivalent to `x>0&&y>0`!